# how to read the file via Windows Explorer which is be holding by StreamWriter?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a windows service which writes logs to a file using StreamWriter.
StreamWriter will hold the log file until the service is stoped.

i want to check the log while the service is still running using Windows Explorer. The erorr is "The file is being used by another process". i thought i could at least copy and paste it, but still same error.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: always close the file handle once done reading/writing will make it available for copy paste and you will not have the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the file share permissions correctly. Right now you have an exclusive "lock" on the file that doesn't allow any other process (including Windows) to open it. When a file is copied, it has to be opened for the data to be read.

```
var fileStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
streamWriter.AutoFlush = true;
```

Now you should be able to write to the file with the stream writer, and read from the file from different processes. Don't forget to Dispose/Close resources when the program terminates.

Comment: This is exactly what i need. i was using FileInfo.Create() as FileStream.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If any files/resource is still in use [handle is not closed] then windows will throw the message. Proper way of using streamwriter is to use it within `using` statement as soon as using block is done it calls internally dispose() method on the streamwriter which shall close the resource and you file shall be available for read/write. here is a example and best place to start [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("CDriveDirs.txt"))
{
   sw.WriteLine(dir.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is that best practice to dispose StreamWriter every time when Write?

Comment: it depends on situation you should dispose or synchronize if two or more processes are writing to sync the writes. otherwise if you want to share at the same time when its written there is a possibility other process may not see the change and they need to read again. but closing the file handle if its not frequent is good.